# What happens if transaction.Rollback/Commit never called in before closing the connection?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, commit, rollback

What happens if transaction.Rollback/Commit never called in before closing the connection ?

```
public DBStatus InsertUpdateUserProfile(Int64 UserID, W_User_Profile oUser)
{
    MySqlConnection oMySQLConnecion = null;
    MySqlTransaction tr = null;
    DBStatus oDBStatus = new DBStatus();
    try
    {
        oMySQLConnecion = new MySqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString);
        if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed || oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken)
        {
            oMySQLConnecion.Open();
        }

        tr = oMySQLConnecion.BeginTransaction();

        if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            string Query = @"INSERT INTO user .....................;"
                            INSERT IGNORE INTO user_role ....................;";

            MySqlCommand oCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, oMySQLConnecion);
            oCommand.Transaction = tr;

            oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);                            
            oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressID", oUser.AddressID);                                 
    ................
    ................


            int sqlSuccess = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (sqlSuccess>0)
            {
                tr.Commit();
                oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.SUCCESS;
                oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.SUCCESSFULLY_DATA_UPDATED);
            }
            oMySQLConnecion.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.ERROR;
            oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.ERROR_DUE_TO_NO_DB_CONNECTION);
        }
        return oDBStatus;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            tr.Rollback();
            oMySQLConnecion.Close();
        }
        oDBStatus.Type = DBOperation.ERROR;
        oDBStatus.Message.Add(DBMessageType.ERROR_OR_EXCEPTION_OCCURED_WHILE_UPDATING);
        oDBStatus.InnerException.Add(ex.Message);
        return oDBStatus;
    }
}
```

In the above function, I do Commit if transaction is successful and Rollback if it fails and connection is still on.

If the connection is terminated there is no Rollback. I read many places that says it will be a automatic Rollback if the connection terminates without Commit (what I want). Is this a bad practice ? I could add try-catch after connection establishes but add little code in every similar functions. Does it really necessary ?

Comment: Do not call `Close`. Use `using`. It will call Dispose, and dispose will roll back an unfinished transaction. That is the normal practice. It would be impossible to handle certain scenarios if it did not roll it back on Dispose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if transaction.Rollback/Commit never called in before closing the connection ?

In MySQL the transaction is rolled back.  But some other table servers commit it on connection close.

**Pro tip**: Don't rely on this behavior except as a way to handle a hard crash.

Comment: @PrakashMhasavekar I think you mean inside the Catch block to rollback. If you did it inside the Finally block then it would always try to rollback even when successfully executed.

Comment: @J.D. My Mistake. It should be `Try { Commit; } Catch { Rollback; } Finally { Dispose; }`